# Google play error "Please check the languages marked above for errors"

Tags: google-play

currently receiving the following error withiin google play under store listing:
Please check the languages marked above for errors.
no matter what language i select this error shows and i am unable to update the store..  How to fix this?

Comment: just a guess: the play store console might want your app's apk file to be uploaded first, if it does not yet have one.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Problem is caused by a mandatory feature graphic, error code is misleading..

Comment: how can it be solved i have to upload an update for my app which i am unable to do

Answer (score 11):

What Tommo said. Apparently it is related to the recent changes to Google Play where a Featured image is required when making any changes to your listing.

> Beginning August 31, 2014, you will be required to submit a Feature
>   Graphic to update your app or Store Listing."

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6066610

Answer (score 2):

Ran into a similar issue today. Turns out, the promo video needs to include "http", "www" will show this misleading validation message.

Answer (score 2):

if anyone getting this error "Some languages have errors" in the main store listing section on the google play console while publishing the app. Then, here is what I did to solve my issue.

- Click on "manage translation" then click on "Manage your own translations". Next, remove all the languages on the "language" column and click "apply".

I hope this should solve your error problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I have now sorted this.  You have to upload a separate short description and Feature Graphic for EACH language that your app supports, otherwise it won't be accepted.  Even if the description and graphic are the same, you have to re-upload for each language.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue. Added the below to get it fixed.

1. Content Rating
2. Short Description of the app
3. Featured Image of 1024*500

Above fields were added later and are mandatory. Post this, just re-submitted the app and it was live again. :)

Answer (score 0):

After uploading the feature graphic, the error was still displayed. You have to click **save and publish** to clear the error.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will have to upload all the sections marked **( * )** with proper dimensions and it will solve the issue.